# p:orderList converter getAsObject() doesn't call Object.toString()

Tags: jsf, primefaces, converters

I've written a custom converter as follows:

```
@FacesConverter(value = "orderListConverter")
public class OrderListConverter implements Converter {

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {

    Object ret = null;
    if (component instanceof OrderList) {
        Object list = ((OrderList) component).getValue();
        ArrayList<ExampleEntity> al = (ArrayList<ExampleEntity>) list;
        for (Object o : al) {
            String name = "" + ((ExampleEntity) o).getName();
            if (value.equals(name)) {
                ret = o;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) 
{
    String str = "";
    if (value instanceof ExampleEntity) {
        str = "" + ((ExampleEntity) value).getNumber();
    }
    return str;
}
}
```

My ExampleEntity is implemented as follows:

```
public class ExampleEntity {

private String name;

private int number;

public ExampleEntity(String name, int number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "toString(): [name=" + name + ", number=" + number + "]";
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}

}
```

the orderList-Component from Primefaces looks like that:

```
<p:orderList value="#{orderListBean.exampleList}"
var="exampleEntity" itemValue="#{exampleEntity}"
converter="orderListConverter">

    <p:column style="width:25%">
        #{exampleEntity.number}
    </p:column>
    <p:column style="width:75%;">
        #{exampleEntity.name}
    </p:column>
</p:orderList>
```

and the bean is implemented as follows:

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "orderListBean")
public class OrderListBean {

private List<ExampleEntity> exampleList;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {

    exampleList = new ArrayList<ExampleEntity>();

    exampleList.add(new ExampleEntity("nameOne", 1));
    exampleList.add(new ExampleEntity("nameTwo", 2));
    exampleList.add(new ExampleEntity("nameThree", 3));
    exampleList.add(new ExampleEntity("nameFour", 4));
    exampleList.add(new ExampleEntity("nameFive", 5));

}

public List<ExampleEntity> getExampleList() {
    return exampleList;
}

public void setExampleList(List<ExampleEntity> exampleList) {
    this.exampleList = exampleList;
}
```

}

1) when debugging, the `value` Parameter of `getAsObject()` contains
the `number` of the `ExampleEntity`, but I had expected the 
`toString()` method of `ExampleEntity` to be called!

2) What is the correct content for `itemValue` attribute? 
Is it a kind of convention over configuration? Or how does the component
'know', to use the whole object, when inserting `exampleEntity` into `itemValue`

Hope everything is clear! Tanks a lot for any explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converters basically serve to transform values in 2 directions:

1. Server to client, when the value is rendered.
2. Client to server, when the value is submitted.

In your `getAsString` you established, that the string representation, the one which client uses, is `exampleEntity`'s number. So that's what gets rendered to client as a value. And later, when the client submits its value, that value is `number`. To convert it to the object (server) representation, the `getAsObject` called with the `number` as a parameter.
The server can't possibly call `getAsObject` with `exampleEntity.toString()`, because it doesn't have the `exampleEntity` instance at that point, only the submitted `number`.

To illustrate, this should hold:

```
obj.equals(conv.getAsObject(ctx, comp, conv.getAsString(ctx, comp, obj)));
```

`getAsObject` and `getAsString` should be inversive in their input and output.

To answer your 2nd question: that depends on your needs. You could say `itemValue="#{exampleEntity.number}"`, but that would make sense only if you're not interested in the `exampleEntity` itself, i.e. on submit you would get the `number` from the client and that's all you need for your server-side logic.

Comment: Question 2: I understand, that `exampleEntity` will return the whole Object. But there is no Annotation or anything else (like for the Bean `(name = "beanName")` so how do I know how to write the correct name. Is it always the class-name with lowercase beginning? It was more or less a guess to write `exampleEntity`

Comment: @bauz_69, in your `p:orderList` you define `value` to say "iterate collection `#{orderListBean.exampleList}`" with `var="exampleEntity"` as the name of the loop variable. You could've just as well made it `var="whatever"` and `itemValue="#{wharever}"`.

Answer (score -1):

```
@FacesConverter(value = "EntityConverter")
public class EntityConverter implements Converter, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public EntityConverter() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(final FacesContext context, final UIComponent component, final String value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return fromSelect(component, value);
    }

    /**
     * @param currentcomponent
     * @param objectString
     * @return the Object
     */
    private Object fromSelect(final UIComponent currentcomponent, final String objectString) {

        if (currentcomponent.getClass() == UISelectItem.class) {
            final UISelectItem item = (UISelectItem) currentcomponent;
            final Object value = item.getValue();
            if (objectString.equals(serialize(value))) {
                return value;
            }
        }

        if (currentcomponent.getClass() == UISelectItems.class) {
            final UISelectItems items = (UISelectItems) currentcomponent;
            final List<Object> elements = (List<Object>) items.getValue();
            for (final Object element : elements) {
                if (objectString.equals(serialize(element))) {
                    return element;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!currentcomponent.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
            for (final UIComponent component : currentcomponent.getChildren()) {
                final Object result = fromSelect(component, objectString);
                if (result != null) {
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }

        if (currentcomponent instanceof OrderList) {
            Object items = ((OrderList) currentcomponent).getValue();
            List<Object> elements = (List<Object>) items;
            for (final Object element : elements) {
                if (objectString.equals(serialize(element))) {
                    return element;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @param object
     * @return the String
     */
    private String serialize(final Object object) {
        if (object == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return object.getClass() + "@" + object.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(final FacesContext arg0, final UIComponent arg1, final Object object) {
        return serialize(object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Bad formatting an no explanation. Effectively not a very good answer. Can you improve it?